# Как сверстать такой блок?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Помогите пожалуйста сверстать такой блок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<div class="about__info">
   <h2>About Us</h2>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do                       eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Я не могу понять, как сверстать заголовок вот таким образом, чтоб он был с позиционирован по отношению этому блоку, я примерно понимаю, но не могу сверстать, из-за того, что я делаю верхнюю границу псевдоэлементами ::before и ::after, задаю их именно заголовку, но при сужении браузера псевдоэлементы начинают плыть, мне нужно их именно как-то зафиксировать сверху этого блока

Comment: опишите вашу проблему в самом вопросе и приложите вашу попытку в виде кода, так вам быстрее помогут)

Comment: А я бы тупо шрифт заголовка сделал бы с паддингми и подложкой того же цвета и поднял бы отрицательным маргином из блока. А блок просто с бордерами обычными.

Comment: "такой" - какой?

Comment: @Movs, Спасибо за ответ, ваш совет очень помог но частично, марджины че-то плохо сработали, но я сделал абсолютное позиционирование по отношению к блоку. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.about__info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  border: 2px solid #948565;
  background-color: #ab9b77;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #ab9b77;
  color: #434242;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.about__info h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1.2em/2);
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.about__info p {
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__info">
   <h2>About Us</h2>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do                       eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отчень хороший ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать тег `fieldset`

```css
body
{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

#about legend {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#about 
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
#about p
{
  margin:30px;
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="about">
  <legend>About us</legend>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: fieldset же используется для группировки формы, так что скорей всего он не подходит, мне нужно обычным способом без fieldset

Comment: Что мешает использовать его в целях стилизации?

Comment: Это не семантично

Comment: В таком случае могу предложить через див